# How can I break decimal numbers like words in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to break numbers with dots and commas just like I break up words. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

"live long and prosper"

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>3.0.0.1.2.3.1.2.3</div>
  <div>Beam me up scotty!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `word-break: break-word` seems to work - any reason you can't use that?

Comment: @SexyTurnip perfect, can you make it as an answer I will be glad to mark it as the answer

Comment: Mark @AminJafari as correct. There is no point duplicating answers

Comment: @SexyTurnip I will, he was the first to put it as an answer, however, I need to wait 7 min to do so, hold on :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `word-wrap:break-word`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygz712j4/)**

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I need to wait 5 more minutes, and I will be able to mark your answer as the answer +1